# How to make pagination working?

Tags: dynatable

I'm trying to create an example of Dynatable with pagination, to do this, I created an html file and a json loaded using Ajax, directly from the same directory as the html file.

The data is rendered correctly, te footer says: "Showing 5 of 5 records (filtered from 45 total records)", that's ok also. The problem is the link at the right, only displays 1 page, when it should show 9 pages.

This is the html content:

```
<body>
<div class="dynatable-demo">    
<table id="my-ajax-table" class="table table-bordered hoverTable">
<thead>
       <tr>
        <th data-dynatable-column="idturno" data-dynatable-no-sort="true">Id Turno</th>
        <th data-dynatable-column="accessionnumber">Accesion Number</th>
        <th data-dynatable-column="apellidopaterno">Apellido Paterno</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script>

$('#my-ajax-table').dynatable({
 dataset: {
    ajax: true,
    ajaxOnLoad: true,
    ajaxUrl: 'consulta.json',
    records: [],
    perPageDefault: 5,
    perPageOptions: [5,10,100]
 }
});
</script>
```

And here's the "consulta.json" file:

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "idturno": "88",
        "accessionnumber": "24471579",
        "apellidopaterno": "DORATO^PABLO EZEQUIEL"
    },
    {
        "idturno": "89",
        "accessionnumber": "0001",
        "apellidopaterno": "apepaterno"
    },
    {
        "idturno": "90",
        "accessionnumber": "0002",
        "apellidopaterno": "apepaterno"
    },
    {
        "idturno": "91",
        "accessionnumber": "0003",
        "apellidopaterno": "apepaterno"
    },
    {
        "idturno": "92",
        "accessionnumber": "0004",
        "apellidopaterno": "apepaterno"
    }
],
"queryRecordCount": 5,
"totalRecordCount": 45
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've too got the same issue, after going through the source found out this.

```
pages = Math.ceil(settings.dataset.queryRecordCount / settings.dataset.perPage)
```

the queryRecordCount is getting divided by the perPage which is equal hence the single page.

It should be the **totalRecordCount** in that place actually. Maybe the issue was at the ajax only. Change the *queryRecordCount*  with **totalRecordCount** and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the code

```
$('#my-ajax-table').dynatable({
dataset: {
    ajax: true,
    ajaxOnLoad: true,
    ajaxUrl: 'consulta.json',
    records: [],
    perPageDefault: 5,
    perPageOptions: [5, 10, 100]
},
features: {
    paginate: true,
    sort: true,
    pushState: false,
    search: true,
    recordCount: true,
    perPageSelect: true
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

After configure pagination parameters ensure that your JSON is returning 'queryRecordCount' AND 'totalRecordCount' fields.

Answer (score 0):

queryRecordCount and totalRecordCount are the same for this query.
Should be

```
"queryRecordCount": 45,
"totalRecordCount": 45
```

It's only differs on filtered queries (?search)